# CSS draw circle left and right out of the box

Tags: html, css

I want to draw two circles in the middle position outside the inner box, but inside the outside box on the left and right side, like the picture shows below. Can someone give me some hint about it?
[image]

```
    <div style="border: 1px solid red; width: 200px">
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
        </div>
        <div style="border: 1px solid red; margin: 0px 20px">
            <p class="title" style="width: 200px">This is a line</p>
            <p class="title" style="width: 200px">This is 2nd line</p>
        </div>
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
```

=============
I used table to simulate, and it seems it is pretty good.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
        </div>
    </th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
        </div>
    </td>
    <th>
            <div style="border: 1px solid red; margin: 0px">
                <p class="title" style="width: 200px">This is a line</p>
                <p class="title" style="width: 200px">This is 2nd line</p>
            </div>
    </th>
    <th>
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
        </div>        
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a mix of relative and absolute positioning here. Relative positioning on the container tells its child elements, "position yourself according to my boundaries". So you can do something like this:

```html
  <div style="border: 1px solid red; width: 200px; position: relative;">
        <div style="text-align: center; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 50%;">
            <i class="fa fa-circle">*</i>
        </div>
        <div style="border: 1px solid red; margin: 0px 20px">
            <p class="title" style="width: 200px">This is a line</p>
            <p class="title" style="width: 200px">This is 2nd line</p>
        </div>
        <div style="text-align: center; position: absolute; right: 0; top: 50%;">
            <i class="fa fa-circle">*</i>
        </div>
    </div>
```

...That being said, inline styles like this are really tough to maintain and become a huge headache over time. You should read up on separating CSS from HTML, move these styles into a stylesheet, and link them back to the elements via classes.

Answer (score 0):

With a little css, this should be very easy! You can set the parent div to `position: relative;`, and the circles to `position: absolute;` with a 
 position i.e. `left: 20px;` or `right: -5%;`. This will tell the circle to move 20px from the left of its parent, the outermost div.

If you want to get the circle exactly in the middle, you should change your px widths to percentages, and use the same `relative`&`absolute` with `position` to move the circles around.

Here's some more info! https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Comment: Thanks. same idea as the other one.

Comment: A very normal pattern for situations like this, worth learning! Tables help logically, and are supported by every browser, but begin to fall short when you need more fine-grained control of positioning, say if you wanted the circle to sit exactly on the lines, or if you wanted them positioned anywhere other than the center of the cell. Glad you found a solution!